# Can I run 2 well tanks from 1 well

Tags: plumbing, water, well-pump, well

I have a detached garage that is in between the well and the house.

As it stands, the tank in the house is not sufficient for watering the lawn, and so I would like to get a bigger one anyhow.  Since the garage is new and closer to the well line than it is the house, I thought maybe I could just buy a bigger tank and hook it up directly in the garage to supply water to the orchard and the upstairs garage apartment (new plumbing).

Otherwise, I would have to bring in a water line from the house to the garage anyway.

The current setup is a well ~300 ft from the house with a 20 gallon pressure tank/bladder in the house.

Comment: Do you mean putting a second pressure tank in the garage? A pressure tank's job is to provide a buffer so the pump doesn't rapid cycle every time you open a tap. If you have a tap open for a while (watering lawn, shower) it's normal that the pump would cycle on/off every few minutes. Can you better explain what you mean by "the tank in the house is not sufficient for watering the lawn"? eg: Are you actually running out of water, is the pump rapid-cycling, or something else?

Comment: How many GPM does the well produce and is your irrigation GPM so high it's running the well dry? At irrigation pressures, the size of the pressure tank matters little, it's whether the sustained flow rate can be delivered by the well. Many people out west will soon be finding that out this year, a 1500 gallon holding tank is more necessary than a wimpy 50 or 100 gallon pressure tank. And the answer is yes, it's just another accumulator in the hydraulic system, but probably not of enough capacity to fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, a second pressure tank in the garage.  The water runs fine NORMALLY but when I water the lawn for a hour or 2, I find that pressure in the house is terribly low for a while, and the lawn is no longer being watered sufficiently once it gets into this state.

purpose is twofold:

Separate the house pressure tank from the lawn/irrigation/garage apartment.  If I use up the garage's tank capacity, I don't affect the water supply/pressure in the house for the most part.

Secondly, I need water supply in the garage anyhow for the apartment ...

Comment: Two tanks, two separate pumps and water systems, in the end will be the answer.

Comment: Two pumps inside of 1 well?